# If I don't provide a gradient for an op in tensorflow, how does gradient descent work?

Tags: tensorflow, operator-keyword, deep-learning

When adding a new op, the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html) says:

***Optionally, write a function to compute gradients for the Op.***

Since this is optional, if I don't write it, how does gradient descent compute the gradient?  Does it use a numerical method?  If so, what?  And would this be slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the operation. If the operation is composed of other primitives then the Gradient Descent is able to product the auto-differentiation function.

If your operation is a *new primitive*, then you must provide a gradient function or gradient descent will not work.

Gradient implementations in Tensorflow are exact functions. The numerical method is implemented only for testing the gradient functions implementations.